# Failed to run ./gradlew signingReport because of java

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio

I tried to run `./gradlew signingReport` it show me error

`ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: F:\java\bin Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.`

Here is JAVA_HOME in user path I also tried setting on System path.
[What's problem with my java?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5FYj.jpg)

For testing,  I tried by setting path to `ENV` only user/only system/both system and user. Every time java is work. but when I try to run `./gradlew signingReport` it shows error for java.

Comment: `signingReport` isn't a standard Gradle task. If you want help, you'll have to tell us where it comes from.

Comment: Try printing the actual `JAVA_HOME` value from somewhere as close to executing that task as possible. Maybe something is overwriting the value you think you have set.

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should point to the installation path of the JDK, not to the path of the `bin` sub-directory of the JDK.

Comment: @Jorn My java is working fine. I can run java programs too. But when I run ./gradlew signingReport for sha256_cert_fingerprints of keystore certificate. It shows error.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I just edit my `JAVA_HOME` variable path `F:\java\bin` -> `F:\java` (Customized installation)

It can be - `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin` -> `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20`